# Error 404 after update to 1.9.2.0 - during registration

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, ce-1.9.2.2, form-key, csrf

After update to 1.9.2.0 I have added the form-key to my registration template.

I can see the form-key value using firebug on the registration page, but when I submit the form, I get a 404 error:

```
http://dev.pickone.com.br/customer/account/createpost/ ---- 404 Not Found
```

I am using nginx/1.2.1. Also using onepagecheckout.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you put an error in the template: The URL should be `/customer/account/createPost` (capital <kbd>P</kbd>)